# Sed replace content from x till y on multi lines

Tags: sed, replace, multiline, marker

I have the following file:

```
2020-04-17 10:35:08.339       msw_im.c   wync_ua[0]DEBUG:  .mark1: lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam 
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren

2020-04-17 10:35:08.340
```

I want to have every char between "mark1:" and and "2020-04-17 10:35:08.340" replaced like this

```
2020-04-17 10:35:08.339       msw_im.c   wync_ua[0]DEBUG:  .mark1: xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxx
xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxx

2020-04-17 10:35:08.340
```

How can I do this? I have tried:

```
$: sed -i '/mark1/,/^$/{s/./x/g}' file
```

which works, but also replaces the beginning of the 1st line with "x". I tried multiple other things w/o success. Any idea?

Comment: Your attempt substitutes every single character between the first and the empty line with `x`. So it's clearly not even close to what you want to get. Furthermore, Can you explain, for instance, where do the 5 `x` in the 3rd output line come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anonymizing lines with GNU sed:

```
sed -E -i '/mark1:/,/^$/{ /mark1:/{ :a;s/(mark1:x*)[^x]/\1x/;ta;b }; s/./x/g }' file
```

Output to file:

```
2020-04-17 10:35:08.339       msw_im.c   wync_ua[0]DEBUG:  .mark1:xxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

2020-04-17 10:35:08.340
```

---

See: `man sed` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)